# "Syntax error, multiple markers at this line"?

Tags: c

I have a while loop in C program which was supposed to wait for system to tweak a single bit (**bit0**) ON and then continue execution. This bit or "flag" is located in a register (**reg1**). I have been trying to program this using bitwise & operator for masking my register like this.

```
unsigned int continue;
while(continue != (reg1 & bit0));
```

I end up getting an error: "**Syntax error, multiple markers at this line, expected ')' before ';' token.**"

Comment: This diagnostic is indeed not very helpful to understand what is going on. gcc and clang give me `expected identifier or '('` for the first line, which is a bit better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`continue` is a keyword. You can't use it as an identifier.

Change the name to something else and see if it works:

```
unsigned int cont = 0;        //  You also forgot to initialize.
while(cont != (reg1 & bit0));
```